# React 17.0.1 - Importing Component with Dynamic Path

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic, import, path

I am trying to learn how to use "useState" hooks using [this guide](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/simplifying-react-state-and-the-usestate-hook) but I can't seem to import images with a dynamic path, so that when I click a button the element gets a new path and changes the image.

Here is how the guide is importing images:

```
...
function App() {
  const [firstDieResult, setFirstDieResult] = useState(1);
  const [secondDieResult, setSecondDieResult] = useState(6);
  
  const firstDieImage = require(`./assets/${firstDieResult}.png`);
  const secondDieImage = require(`./assets/${secondDieResult}.png`);
...
```

However, when I try to import images this way it wont import them. I am importing them as such:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import firstDieImage from './assets/1.png'
import secondDieImage from './assets/2.png'

function App() {
...
```

But when I import them this way, I can't import a dynamic path (like `import firstDieImage from './assets/${firstDieResult}.png'`).

How do I go about importing images this way?
Thank you for your time.

Whole code for reference:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import firstDieImage from './assets/1.png'
import secondDieImage from './assets/2.png'

function App() {

  const [firstDieResult, setFirstDieResult] = useState(1)
  const [secondDieResult, setSecondDieResult] = useState(6)
  console.log(secondDieResult)
  
  //Commented out parts work in the guide, but not for me
  //const firstDieImage = require('./assets/1.png')
  //const secondDieImage = require('./assets/2.png')
  //const firstDieImage = require('./assets/${firstDieResult}.png')
  //const secondDieImage = require('./assets/${secondDieResult}.png');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', margin: 20 }}>
          <img src={firstDieImage} className="die" alt="Die one" />
          <img src={secondDieImage} className="die" alt="Die two" />
        </div>
        <span>firstDieResult + secondDieResult</span>
        <button className="button">Roll</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a mistake.

```js
const firstDieImage = require('./assets/${firstDieResult}.png')
```

You should use backtick character (`) instead of a single quote ('). And if you create project using **create-react-app** module, update the code like this:

```js
const firstDieImage = require(`./assets/${firstDieResult}.png`).default
```

You can find working code from this [git repo](https://github.com/DarkPonyBee/stackoverflow-dynamic-image-answer).

Comment: Backticks and single quotes work the same, at least in this instance.

Comment: Did you check the codesandbox link?
Please check the code. You can find code is working with backticks.

Comment: I did, and the code that works in the link doesn't work on my VS Code. Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Fork the codesandbox project to your github.
Then clone it and try to run again.

Comment: Finally finished forking it to VS Code (first time) and the code doesn't work.

Comment: Post your react version.

Comment: "react": "^17.0.1",  
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",  
"react-router": "^5.2.0",  
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",  
"react-scripts": "4.0.1"

Comment: @Krokzter Updated the answer.
This code will work on your VS Code.

Comment: Yes, that did work, thank you so much for your time. One thing to note for anyone coming across this in the future, as of this time React doesn't work with Typescript 4 or above, so uninstall it using "npm remove typescript" and then install it again using "npm i typescript". It will install Typescript 3.9.7.